# Dynamic range with absolute start cell in an excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells

In a column headed "Fred Count" I have the formula =COUNTIF(L$2:L10,"Fred") in row 10 where column L  is headed "Person" and contains various names, so as I drag the formula down the "Fred Count" column it shows the number of times Fred appears in Person column at the current row or above.

How do I write the formula to use the table nomenclature? I've tried various combinations, but haven't hit on theone that works.

tia

Comment: what do you mean by "table nomenclature"? Something like `[[#All][Person]]`? There is no way for that. You can use only if you refer to the current row, or the whole column.

Comment: (I had been assuming using "table references" I could at least reconstruct the range with an absolute reference to the first data cell in the Person column and a reference to the cell in the current row.)

Comment: You can't refer to the cell in the first row with data, but what's more important: can't compose those two references to be considered as start and end of a range:( (maybe you could with `ADDRESS` and `INDIRECT` functions, but this would make your formula too complicated). Maybe you could use this one: `=COUNTIF(OFFSET([@[Person]],-(ROW()-2),0,ROW()-1,1),"Fred")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not possible to refer part of a column by using structured references, you can combine current row with `OFFSET` for the desired result:

`=COUNTIF(OFFSET([@[Person]],-(ROW()-2),0,ROW()-1,1),"Fred")`

(Alternatively you could do it with ADDRESS and INDIRECT functions, but this would make your formula too much complicated).